# UTF-8 not working in HTML forms

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have this form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

But when I submit an é character, it turns it into Ã©.

Why doesn't this work? Yes, the MySQL database has all the character-sets set up correctly. (Database, tables.) If I manually put it in the database with Navicat it shows up fine on the webpage.

Also, I have tried the metatag, setting the content-type header, without success.

Comment: How are you putting the form data into the database? Is your server side language preserving UTF-8?

Comment: Are you serving your page as UTF-8 when you display it back to the user? Check that your meta tags and headers match.

Comment: All fields go through mysql_real_escape_string, and are then put in the database using this query:

mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `Profile`='".$newProfile."',`Avatar`='".mysql_real_escape_string($avatar)."' WHERE `ID`=".$thisUser['ID']);

Comment: notJim: the Ã© also appears in the database itself, which means that the clients are not sending it correctly, and thus a problem with either HTML or PHP that's not doing it right.

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details to the question, instead of a comment.

Comment: When you say "appears in the database itself", which mysql client are you using to see that? I've encountered issues with utf-8 values in various clients including Mysql Query Browser. 

If you select the value back into php, with utf-8 headers et al properlty set, does it display it garbled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your HTML, add this meta tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Also add this PHP header at top of the script:

```
 header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

**[EDIT]:**

One more tip is to save the file as `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding. You can use [Notepad++](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/) or any decent editor to do that.

Comment: Have both, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have the `header` at the top in the HTML page where the form is ?

Comment: @angelo, what do you mean by *extra characters* ? Also, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @shamittomar, I did that because only "Yes" is a too short comment :)

Comment: Also, the database CAN contain the correct characters, and CAN return the correct characters, which the page can display correctly. It really is PHP that's not sending it correctly (or the browser)

Comment: So, did you save it with `UTF-8 without BOM` ?

Answer (score 2):

Had the exactly same problem as mentioned above, tried everything mentioned.
Try deleting 
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`
and adding
`accept-charset="utf-8"`
from the  tag. This was the solution in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have set your connection collation to `utf8`:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Comment: Is the form page utf-8 as well? Also, did you try another browser/machine?

Comment: I just tried Internet Explorer, same problem. Other users also experience this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add only accept-charset="character_set" in form. It is all!

```
accept-charset="character_set"
```