# Issue with utf-8 string on url when I send via form get method

Tags: php, string, forms, url, utf-8

I have a form like this to send a utf-8 string parameter.

```
<form rel="search" action="/archives" method="get">

 <input name="key" type="text" value="تست" />

 <input type="submit" value="submit"  />

</form>
```

But the url changes to

```
http://localhost/archives?key=%26%231578%3B%26%231587%3B%26%231578%3B
```

and value of this parameters in destination is wrong: `*3*`

Is there a way to avoide encode in url like this: `http://localhost/archives?key=تست`

because if I enter `http://localhost/archives?key=تست` in my browser,value of this parameters in destination is true...also encode stirng is ugly in the url

Comment: Are you adding <meta charset="utf-8" /> to your page head?

Comment: No...But I think You are right. I add UTF-8 to the head form and it works now. :)

Comment: Ok. I'm glad it was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL change you are seeing is perfectly normal: The browser needs to [URL encode](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent&ei=KClWU-SeNaPx0gXj8YGgDg&usg=AFQjCNHX0ygw68r1tvp2UFzOB-t7B5in1Q&sig2=fSGs7vXCLCkob7ehROpAfg&bvm=bv.65177938,d.d2k) the request to create a valid URL query string. PHP automatically URL decodes all [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) parameters so you don't need to care about this.

First of all: is the charset of your html correctly set to utf-8?

http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset

html5:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

other html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

on xhtml too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Second: is your web server serving utf-8? Is the browser establishing utf-8 encoding on the get request?

On apache, you can set the encoding on httpd.conf:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Also, you can set the header on PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

You can check the content-type header of served document and the get request using the network tab on developer tools (ctrl+shift+i on chrome)

Third: Check out this mbstring cheasheet to properly handle multibyte charsets in PHP

http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Also, check out this other answer:

[UTF-8 not working in HTML forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624681/utf-8-not-working-in-html-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending information to the server, why not use POST? In this case no parameters will be seen in the URL.

```
<form rel="search" action="/archives" method="post">

 <input name="key" type="text" value="تست" />

 <input type="submit" value="submit"  />

</form>
```

and you can read the parameter using

```
$_POST['key']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "post" method instead? It will completely hide your url and any kind of encoding.