# Norwegian letters "æ, ø, å" not showing when contact form is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, utf-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a contact form, you can view it [here](http://fantasylab.no/projects/comingsoon). When I fill out the contact form and go to my inbox folder - the Norwegian letters æ, ø, å aren't shown in the message.

This is what I have currently added:

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="ISO-8859-1">`

I have also tried `<form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">`, but with no luck.

Here is a screenshot from the e-mail I receive after contact form has been submitted
[image]
as you can see there are no æ, ø, å letters.

Is there any way I can fix this?

PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $from = 'Ny melding sendt fra kontaktskjema på Helsespesialisten.no'; 
    $to = 'test@test'; 
    $subject = 'Helsespesialisten | Du har motatt en ny melding';

    $body = "Fra: $name\n E-post: $email\n Telefonnummer: $number\n Melding: $message\n";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Vennligst skriv inn ditt navn';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Vennligst skriv inn din e-post';
    }

    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['number']) {
        $errNumber = 'Vennligst skriv inn ditt telefonnummer';
    }


    //Check if message has been entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Vennligst skriv en melding';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errNumber && !$errMessage) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from, $number)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Takk for din henvendelse! Vi tar kontakt i løpet av kort tid!</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Beklager, en feil skjedde! Kontakt oss på: +47 35 11 15 40</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try UTF-8 instead just as you tagged it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've tried that also

Comment: is the file saved "as" UTF-8?

Comment: UTF8 is def the answer...

Comment: Are you implementing both sides or just coding up the form to send. What is the email client you are reading it in?

Comment: @Fred How can I check if the file is saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Ive never experienced this myself, and im not using any charset. It might be dependant on the email application you use as well.

Comment: Use a code editor and see the file's encoding. I use Notepad++ myself. You will have a choice between UTF-8 with, or without BOM (byte order mark). Try both.

Comment: @AdamJeffers I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird, i'm implementing both I believe. I edited code with UTF-8, but still same problem

Comment: @KristianHareland I'll check with Thunderbird, but usually when I write other e-mails the letters show up, so I think its somewhere in the coding i'm missing something.

Comment: And changin to "<meta charset="UTF-8">" makes no difference?

Comment: @AdamJeffers Correct.

Comment: Whatever editor you're using, go to 'save with encoding' or something similar and try to save it as UTF-8... I use sublime

Comment: this might be something you should look into: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: I checked encoding in Sublime and it says: UTF-8

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through there may be additional information in there that you may not be doing.

Comment: Have you got the language pack installed on the machine you are reading the email on?

Comment: He is norwegian based off his screenshot so i would guess he has it installed

Comment: Yes, language pack is installed. I write/receive norwegian emails everyday through Thunderbird without any problems, but when receiving email from contact-form, the letters don't show.

Comment: Since you're not using any non-ascii characters **in your PHP source code**, it doesn't matter how your .php file is encoded. However your source code

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3624681/1336342)?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, posted to early, I meant: if you're not using any non-ascii characters **in your PHP source code**, it doesn't matter how your .php file is encoded. However your php contains chars like å so then it matters (in that case, make sure it's utf-8). But what matters most is the encoding used and specified by your HTML, and that's already utf-8 due to your `http-equiv="content-type"` header. 
Forget about the `accept-charset` in your `<form>` tag, just make sure to interpret the submitted form data as utf-8 (since that's what your html also specifies), and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                        $name = $_POST['name'];
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $message = $_POST['message'];
                        $number = $_POST['number'];
                        $from = 'Ny melding sendt fra kontaktskjema på Helsespesialisten.no'; 
                        $to = 'test@test'; 
                        $subject = 'Helsespesialisten | Du har motatt en ny melding';

                        $headerFields = array(
                            "From: $from",
                            "MIME-Version: 1.0",
                            "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8"
                        );

                        $body = "Fra: $name\n E-post: $email\n Telefonnummer: $number\n Melding: $message\n";

                        // Check if name has been entered
                        if (!$_POST['name']) {
                            $errName = 'Vennligst skriv inn ditt navn';
                        }

                        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
                        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $errEmail = 'Vennligst skriv inn din e-post';
                        }

                        //Check if message has been entered
                        if (!$_POST['number']) {
                            $errNumber = 'Vennligst skriv inn ditt telefonnummer';
                        }


                        //Check if message has been entered
                        if (!$_POST['message']) {
                            $errMessage = 'Vennligst skriv en melding';
                        }

                // If there are no errors, send the email
                if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errNumber && !$errMessage) {
                    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headerFields))) {
                        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Takk for din henvendelse! Vi tar kontakt i løpet av kort tid!</div>';
                    } else {
                        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Beklager, en feil skjedde! Kontakt oss på: +47 35 11 15 40</div>';
                    }
                }
                    }
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with PHP, but I have added the current PHP I'm using in the post, are you able to help me update the code? (Tar det på engelsk, for at andre skal forstå, er ikke jeg som har skrevet PHP koden, men min partner :))

Comment: Edited answer :) @NohmanJ, legg meg gjerne til på faceB eller noe dersom du trenger mer hjelp :)

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks! (Takker og bukker! :D )