# HTML formsfails to post in UTF-8 - despite trying recommendations

Tags: php, html, forms, encoding, utf-8

After reading a number of similar questions ([UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), php form submit utf8? [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902062/php-form-submit-utf8), UTF-8 not working in HTML forms [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624681/utf-8-not-working-in-html-forms)) and trying all their recommendations, but the user form in my application still can't handle special characters (é, è, etc). A few additional notes:

- I can save special characters on the db (Postgres), adding new users or editing existing entries, with no problem. And  if I retrieve those entries on the webapp it successfully displays special characters (say, adminPage/usersTable or adminPage/userInfoEdit#).
- However, if I try saving that entry it will write gibberish into the db.

**PHP Header**

```
  <?php header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```

**PHP Post**

```
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $registerData = array(
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'first_name' => $_POST['firt_name'],
        'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    );
registerUser($registerData);
```

**PHP Function**

```
function registerUser($registerData) {
    array_walk($registerData, 'arraySanitize');
pg_query("INSERT INTO utilisateur ($fields, date_inscription, statut) VALUES ($data, '$date','$statut')");
function arraySanitize(&$item) {
    $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(pg_escape_string($item)));
}
```

**HTML form**

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>First name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firt_name" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Last name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firt_name" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>email *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Any comments, suggestions, tips, resources will be highly appreciated. If you have any questions, I'm happy to clarify. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Does your HTML `<head>` have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag?

Comment: Yes @kmoser:  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>